# How to make a colorful gradient glow around your input-box?

Tags: html, css

I know that for blue glow around the box, we just need to applied the code below to our CSS:

[image]

```
.glowing-border {
    border: 2px solid #dadada;
    border-radius: 7px;
}

.glowing-border:focus { 
    outline: none;
    border-color: #9ecaed;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

---

Now I want to take my input-box to a next level.

[image]

I want it to look like this - rather than blue glow. 
I want to have a nice rainbow gradient effect on it.

Is there any CSS Expert out there and think that this is doable for me ?

---

Don't have to be CSS, if someone have any suggestion on how to get this done in a different way - 
please leave a comment or answer.

Comment: I don't think box-shadow supports gradient, but you could probably do some background image magic with it.

Comment: Why try (if even posible) to make that with css when you can make another div under your input, place an image that you create with all the colors needed and just add border radius...I know you could do something like this using css3 gradient and add procentage for each color but why do it like that?

Comment: Make your button an image. Don't try this with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do that by using two additional `divs`. One to be the wrap (also having the background gradient) with an white inset box shadow for the feather effect, and one `div` behind the input area with a white background and outer box shadow.

[image]

I assumed that you form background color is white.

```
.rainbowWrap {
    width: 200px;
    background: //your gradient...
    padding: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 3px white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.rainbowBg {
    width: 184px;
    height:15px;
    background: white;
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 7px 2px white, 0px 0px 13px 2px white;
    border-radius: 4px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.rainbow {
    width:186px;
    background:transparent;
    border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;    
    outline:none;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    z-index: 500;
    color:#666;
}
```

Note that I have only wrote code and only tested in Google Chrome.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b03acbdu/5/

Comment: Thanks. The gradient was generated with this tool: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `svg` solution for this.

The `input` element is positioned inside the `svg` and it is made transparent, so that it looks like the `svg` is the border of the `input` element.

[image]

---

```css
input {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
.input-container-1,
.input-container-2,
.input-container-3 {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.input-container-1 {
  position: relative;
  left: -100px;
  width: 640px;
}
.input-1 {
  width: 360px;
  height: 24px;
  top: 35px;
  left: 136px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.input-container-2 {
  position: relative;
  left: 15px;
  width: 400px;
}
.input-2 {
  width: 217px;
  height: 17px;
  top: 20px;
  left: 87px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.input-container-3 {
  position: relative;
  left: 115px;
  width: 200px;
}
.input-3 {
  width: 110px;
  height: 9px;
  top: 24px;
  left: 43px;
  font-size: 9px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="linearGradient4466">
      <stop style="stop-color:#3d0f00;stop-opacity:1" offset="0" />
      <stop offset="0.11958463" style="stop-color:#3b3d00;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="0.29933503" style="stop-color:#013d00;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="0.52438051" style="stop-color:#003d3d;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="0.69545531" style="stop-color:#00003d;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="0.88148439" style="stop-color:#3d003d;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop style="stop-color:#38000d;stop-opacity:1" offset="1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearGradient3978">
      <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#ffd4bf;stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop style="stop-color:#f8ffbf;stop-opacity:1" offset="0.11958463" />
      <stop style="stop-color:#bfffc0;stop-opacity:1" offset="0.29933503" />
      <stop style="stop-color:#bffbff;stop-opacity:1" offset="0.52438051" />
      <stop style="stop-color:#c2bfff;stop-opacity:1" offset="0.69545531" />
      <stop style="stop-color:#febfff;stop-opacity:1" offset="0.88148439" />
      <stop offset="1" style="stop-color:#ffbfd2;stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linearGradient3924">
      <stop style="stop-color:#ffd4bf;stop-opacity:1" offset="0" />
      <stop offset="0.03125" style="stop-color:#ffd5bf;stop-opacity:1;" />
      <stop offset="0.0625" style="stop-color:#ffd6bf;stop-opacity:1;" />
      <stop offset="0.125" style="stop-color:#ffd8bf;stop-opacity:1;" />
      <stop offset="0.25" style="stop-color:#ffddbf;stop-opacity:1;" />
      <stop offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#ffe6bf;stop-opacity:1;" />
      <stop style="stop-color:#fff8bf;stop-opacity:1" offset="1" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient xlink:href="#linearGradient3924" x1="1390.6012" y1="-164.2403" x2="1397.4197" y2="-164.24028" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" />
    <linearGradient xlink:href="#linearGradient3978" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="1390.6012" y1="-164.11403" x2="1489.2173" y2="-164.49281" gradientTransform="matrix(1.0010509,0,0,1.0060612,-93.175264,9.3454472)" />
    <linearGradient xlink:href="#linearGradient3978" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1.0010509,0,0,1.0060612,-93.10075,-49.919881)" x1="1390.6012" y1="-164.11403" x2="1489.2173" y2="-164.49281" />
    <linearGradient xlink:href="#linearGradient4466" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1.0010509,0,0,1.0060612,-93.100798,-49.919876)" x1="1390.6012" y1="-164.11403" x2="1489.2173" y2="-164.49281" />
    <filter id="filter4482" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" x="-0.30000001" y="-0.30000001" width="1.6" height="1.6">
      <feBlend blend="normal" mode="screen" in2="SourceGraphic" result="result93" />
      <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" operator="over" result="result92" in2="result93" />
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="result91" />
    </filter>
    <linearGradient xlink:href="#linearGradient3978" id="linearGradient4494" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1.0010509,0,0,1.0060612,-93.10075,-49.919881)" x1="1390.6012" y1="-164.11403" x2="1489.2173" y2="-164.49281" />
    <linearGradient xlink:href="#linearGradient4466" id="linearGradient4496" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="matrix(1.0010509,0,0,1.0060612,-93.100798,-49.919876)" x1="1390.6012" y1="-164.11403" x2="1489.2173" y2="-164.49281" />
    <g id="shape" transform="translate(0,-1028.3622)">
      <g transform="translate(-1268.4495,1255.3775)">
        <path d="m 1300.3557,-222.51533 c -1.0545,0 -1.9062,0.85169 -1.9062,1.90625 l 0,11.1875 c 0,1.05456 0.8517,1.90625 1.9062,1.90625 l 96.1876,0 c 1.0545,0 1.9062,-0.85169 1.9062,-1.90625 l 0,-11.1875 c 0,-1.05456 -0.8517,-1.90625 -1.9062,-1.90625 l -96.1876,0 z m 0.6563,1 94.8437,0 c 0.8743,0 1.5938,0.68825 1.5938,1.5625 l 0,9.84375 c 0,0.87425 -0.7195,1.59375 -1.5938,1.59375 l -94.8437,0 c -0.8743,0 -1.5625,-0.7195 -1.5625,-1.59375 l 0,-9.84375 c 0,-0.87425 0.6882,-1.5625 1.5625,-1.5625 z"
        style="fill:url(#linearGradient4494);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" />
        <path style="fill:url(#linearGradient4496);fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;filter:url(#filter4482)" d="m 1300.3557,-222.51533 c -1.0545,0 -1.9062,0.85169 -1.9062,1.90625 l 0,11.1875 c 0,1.05456 0.8517,1.90625 1.9062,1.90625 l 96.1876,0 c 1.0545,0 1.9062,-0.85169 1.9062,-1.90625 l 0,-11.1875 c 0,-1.05456 -0.8517,-1.90625 -1.9062,-1.90625 l -96.1876,0 z m 0.6563,1 94.8437,0 c 0.8743,0 1.5938,0.68825 1.5938,1.5625 l 0,9.84375 c 0,0.87425 -0.7195,1.59375 -1.5938,1.59375 l -94.8437,0 c -0.8743,0 -1.5625,-0.7195 -1.5625,-1.59375 l 0,-9.84375 c 0,-0.87425 0.6882,-1.5625 1.5625,-1.5625 z"
        />
      </g>
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>

<div class="input-container-1">
  <svg width="640" height="96" viewBox="0 0 160 24">
    <use xlink:href="#shape" />
  </svg>
  <input type="text" class="input-1" value="This is the input box" />
</div>
<div class="input-container-2">
  <svg width="400" height="60" viewBox="0 0 160 24">
    <use xlink:href="#shape" />
  </svg>
  <input type="text" class="input-2" value="This is the input box" />
</div>
<div class="input-container-3">
  <svg width="200" height="60" viewBox="0 0 160 24">
    <use xlink:href="#shape" />
  </svg>
  <input type="text" class="input-3" value="This is the input box" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just do it with a background image:

```
#it:focus {
   outline: none;
   border: none;
   box-shadow: none;
   padding: 20px 0px;

   background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbM0u.png') no-repeat;
   background-size: 100%;
}
```

Adjust the padding to match the actual image you make (focus more on aspect ratio than pixels so it scales nicely), then do the same thing for the non-focused case. #it is an input btw. You should be able to do it with a wrapper element.

`background-size` will make it fit everywhere as long as you have the percentage paddings right.

Comment: [HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBMgvW) what I have ! Can you help me adjust it ?

Comment: `   background-size: 100% 100%;  padding: 1% 1.5%;` looks pretty good with that image. The background-size 100% 100% tells it to use all width and height, regardless of aspect ratio. Then the padding I just guess and checked until it looked ok.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I was going to suggest using `border-image` with a CSS gradient:

```css
#t {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border-image-source: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #f932fc 0%, #bc26bf 10%, #7db9e8 41%, #85f78f 61%, #eff484 81%, #ff8c8e 100%);
  border-image-source: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f932fc 0%, #bc26bf 10%, #7db9e8 41%, #85f78f 61%, #eff484 81%, #ff8c8e 100%);
  border-image-source: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #f932fc 0%, #bc26bf 10%, #7db9e8 41%, #85f78f 61%, #eff484 81%, #ff8c8e 100%);
  border-image-source: linear-gradient(to right, #f932fc 0%, #bc26bf 10%, #7db9e8 41%, #85f78f 61%, #eff484 81%, #ff8c8e 100%);
  border-image-width: 2px;
  border-image-repeat: stretch;
  border-image-slice: 2;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="t">
```

But then I realized you wanted an actual *glow* effect.  In that case, you can still use `border-image` with an actual image.

```css
#t {
  width: 694px;
  height: 174px;
  border-image-source: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9h1v.png);
  border-image-width: 45px;
  border-image-repeat: stretch;
  border-image-slice: 81;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="t">
```