# Div appearing behind input

Tags: html, css, z-index

I was trying to answer this question: [How to make a colorful gradient glow around your input-box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27335015/how-to-make-a-colorful-gradient-glow-around-your-input-box/27337185#27337185)

My problem and question is why does the rainbowBg div appear `over` the `input` and not behind it? I have tried positioning the input `absolute`, setting `z-indexes`, nothing worked.

```
<div class="rainbowWrap">
    <div class="rainbowBg"></div>
    <input class="rainbow" type="text"/>
</div>
```

Try typing in the input. You can only focus it if you click between the input border and the `rainbowBg` div. I have only tested in Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/b03acbdu/4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

z-index only works when you define position.  Add "position: relative" to your rainbow class.

Comment: Oh my god. You are right. I feel stupid now that I have wasted so much time o this, I thought I have already tried that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just give the `div` a negative `z-index`. You can even remove `z-index` from the input then.

```
.rainbowBg {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b03acbdu/6/

It goes behind the `input` because `z-index` is ingored for non-positioned elements and so givern a fixed value of 0. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index):

> When no z-index property is specified, elements are rendered on the default rendering layer 0 (zero).

In terms of `z-index` being relative to parent or the whole document, MDN again has a useful article describing [The Stacking Context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context). The children of `.rainbowWrap` are put into their own stacking context, so because `.rainbowBg` is a child of it, it will always be "on top of" it's prent's background. Or as the article puts it better:

> An easy way to figure out the rendering order of stacked elements along the Z axis is to think of it as a "version number" of sorts, where child elements are minor version numbers underneath their parent's major version numbers.

Comment: Is `z-index` relative to document or parent? Because having the `div` inside with negative index should place it behind it's parent if it is relative to document.

Comment: And also, why setting the z-index negative puts it behind the `input`?